# Is there any way to accomplish this in IBM DB2 enviroment

Tags: case, ibm-midrange, db2-400

In DB2 is there a way to basically say:

case when sku (select * from table1 where tb1field = 'SMOMD') then 'True' end

Okay so this is my query so far, I've been going at this for at least a month now so any help would be great.

```
select tb4.customer, tb4.sku, tb4.qty, tb4.retqty, tb4.stipqty, tb4.lastdate, tb4.firstdate, tb4.stipdate

from(
--Table 4
select tb3.Customer as Customer, tb3.sku as SKU, tb3.qty as Qty, tb3.retqty as RetQty, tb3.stipqty as STIPQty,
case when tb3.lastdate is null then '00/0000' else substr(tb3.lastdate,5,2)||'/'||substr(tb3.lastdate,1,4) end as LastDate,
case when tb3.firstdate is null then '00/0000' else substr(tb3.firstdate,5,2)||'/'||substr(tb3.firstdate,1,4) end as FirstDate,
case when tb3.stipdate is null then '00/0000' else substr(tb3.stipdate,5,2)||'/'||substr(tb3.stipdate,1,4) end as STIPDate

from(
--Table 3
select tb2.Customer as Customer, tb2.SKU as SKU, tb2.Qty as Qty, tb2.RetQty as RetQty, tb2.STIPQty as STIPQty,
max(case when tb2.TranID in ('010','100') then tb2.datenum end) as LastDate,
min(case when tb2.TranID in ('010','100') then tb2.datenum end) as FirstDate,
case when tb2.RC = '4M' then tb2.datenum end as STIPDate

from(
--Table 2
select tb1.Customer as Customer, tb1.SKU as SKU,
sum(case when tb1.TranID in ('010','100') then abs(tb1.OrdNet) else '0' end) as Qty,
sum(case when tb1.TranID = '500' and tb1.rc != '4M' then abs(tb1.OrdNet) else '0' end) as RetQty,
count(case when tb1.rc = '4M' then tb1.sku end) as STIPQty,
tb1.datenum as datenum, tb1.TranID as tranid, tb1.RC as rc

from(
--Table 1
select distinct stkund as Customer, sthptg||space(1)||stmodl||space(1)||stvari||space(1)||stfarb||space(1)||stgroe as SKU, 
stvorg as TranID, stggru as RC, stprg09 as PG9, stprg08 as PG8, stperi as datenum, ormne1 as OrdNet
from st_usus.s_stati_pv
join caspdtau.cospf440 on stadrn = jadr40
where trim(stvert) in ('111S','122S')
and sthptg != 'V'
and aktv40 = 'A'
and stprg01 in ('01','04')
and stprg02 = '01'
and stvorg in ('500','010','100')
and stperi >= '20160100'

) as tb1
group by tb1.Customer, tb1.SKU, tb1.datenum, tb1.tranid, tb1.rc


) as tb2
group by tb2.customer, tb2.sku, tb2.qty, tb2.retqty, tb2.stipqty, tb2.tranid, tb2.rc, tb2.datenum

) as tb3
group by tb3.customer, tb3.sku, tb3.qty, tb3.retqty, tb3.stipqty, tb3.lastdate, tb3.firstdate, tb3.stipdate

) as tb4
order by tb4.Customer, tb4.sku
```

Comment: `case when sku (select * from table1...`: to which part of your query does that refer? I cannot locate the area.

Comment: I'm really confused as to what you are asking here.  Can you please explain what problem you are trying to solve?  Also, are you missing something in your case expression?  Should it maybe be `case when sku IN (select SOMEFIELD from table1...`?

Comment: I think you also want to take a look at `ifnull` for some of those case expressions: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzscaifnull.htm

Comment: Can you post the DDL of your tables?

Comment: In addition to DDL, please add some sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to try to decipher exactly what you're trying to do...

Some general advice, rather than using Nested Table Expressions (NTE)

```
select <..> from (select <...>from mytable)
```

Consider Common Table Expressions (CTE)

```
with 
  table1 as (select <...> from st_usus.s_stati_pv join caspdtau.cospf440 on stadrn = jadr40)
, table2 as (select <...> from table1)
, table3 as (select <...> from table2)
, table4 as (select <....> from table3)
select <...> from table4;
```

Each CTE (ie. tableX) can refer to a prior CTE or a physical table/view as needed.  The final select can refer to one or more CTE's along with one or more physical tables or views.

Nice thing about building with CTE's, is that you can check your results after each step..

```
with 
  table1 as (select <...> from st_usus.s_stati_pv join caspdtau.cospf440 on stadrn = jadr40)
select * from table1;
```